# Cannot read property 'Chart' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I want to present a pie chat, the data came from csv file (excel).
I have html file (index.html) and js file (loadData2.js), 
when I print the data in js file I get It like : word,number
donald,8
trump,12
refused ,2
to,7
release ,3
his,6

so I see the data ok.
one field is a word and the other is a number.

I get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).CanvasJSChart is not a function(…)"

my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hw 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="includes/loadData2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="canvas/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
        <script>
        (function(){
            getData2();
        })();
        </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my js code:

```
function getData2()
{
    console.log("hello");
$.get('data/words.csv', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //Better to construct options first and then pass it as a parameter
  var options = {
    exportEnabled: true,
                animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
      text: "Exporting Chart as Image"
    },
    data: [
    {
      type: "splineArea", //change it to line, area, bar, pie, etc
      dataPoints: [data]
    }
    ]
  };
  $("#chartContainer").CanvasJS.Chart(options);
});

}
```

what I need to do to in order to see my chart on the screen?
Thanks,

Comment: what is `CanvasJSChart`? where does it come from?

Comment: have you tried to read the manual for your script? Like this http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/

Answer (score 0):

You are including CanvasJs, and trying to use its jQuery plugin.

replace `<script src="canvas/canvasjs.min.js"></script>` by the right file and it'll work.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

To create a Chart using the regular library would go like this :

```
var options = {
    exportEnabled: true,
                animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
      text: "Exporting Chart as Image"
    },
    data: [
    {
      type: "splineArea", //change it to line, area, bar, pie, etc
      dataPoints: [data]
    }
    ]
  };

  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",options);
  chart.render
```

Comment: I tried this I have no error in my console but it doesnt show anything on the screen